# PHP mkdir not working in if statement

Tags: php, function, codeigniter, mkdir

Why is my `mkdir` not working within the `if(is_dir)` function but it is working above it with just the single line?

```
mkdir($location.$folderName, 0777);

            if(!is_dir($folderName))
            {   
                mkdir($location.$folderName, 0777);

            }else{

            //Set File Settings 
              $config['upload_path'] = $location.$folderName; 
              $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|pdf'; 
              $config['file_name'] = $folderName.'_'.$concept;
              $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
              $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
              $config['max_size'] = '1024'; 
              $config['max_width'] = '1024'; 
              $config['max_height'] = '768'; 

              $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

                print_r($config);

              if(!$this->upload->do_upload($conceptOne)) { #= try upload

                $data['uploadError'] = array('uploadError' => $this->upload->display_errors()); #Error

                $this->load->view('layout', $data);

          } // Do upload
              else{
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data($conceptOne));

              }// end else
            }// end if folder
```

Comment: "not working" means you need to think harder.

Comment: Define "not working". Is the `if` branch even executed at all? How did you confirm that it's "not working"?

Comment: Without knowing what you're passing through, is the $folderName in the same directory as this script is executing from? eg. /scripts/script.php is the code above, but you are making a directory in /files/<new directory>. Might want to put the absolute path in and see what happens. EDIT: if(!is_dir($location.$folderName))

Comment: @Cumbo Post that as an answer,  The swearing has not stopped yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code contradict its self ...   you are calling `mkdir ( $location . $folderName, 0777 );` but checking `! is_dir ( $folderName ))` definitely this would not work

Try

```
$location  = "" ; // Your Location 
$foldername = "" ; // Your Folder Name
$path = $location . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $foldername ;

if (!is_dir ( $path )) {

    if(is_writable($location))
    {
        mkdir ($path, 0777 );
    }
    else
    {
        die("You don't have permission to create folder");
    }
}

 else {
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
if (!(file_exists($folderName))) {
```